# Why does it appear in english?

Tags: line-breaking, languages, line-spacing

I have used the following commands:

```
\begin{proof} 
\begin{enumerate}[i.] 
\item \begin{description} 
\item[Βάση επαγωγής] : Για $m=2$ έχουμε $X_2(a)+\alpha (a)Y_2(a)=(\alpha (a))^2=a\alpha (a)+1$. Άρα $X_2(a)=1, Y_2(a)=a$. Δηλαδή $\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}} (X_2)=0=2-2$ και $\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(Y_2)=1=2-1$. 
\item[Επαγωγική υπόθεση] : Υποθέτουμε ότι ισχύει για $m=k$, δηλαδή $\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(X_k)=k-2$ και $\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(Y_k)=k-1$. (Ε.Υ.) 
\item[Επαγωγικό βήμα] : Θα δείξουμε ότι ισχύει για $m=k+1$, δηλαδή $\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(X_{k+1})=k-1$ και $\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}Y_{k+1})=k$. 
\begin{align*}X_{k+1}+\alpha Y_{k+1}= & (a+\alpha (a))^{-(k+1)}=(a+\alpha (a))^{-k}(a+\alpha (a))^{-1} \\ = & (X_k+\alpha (a)Y_k)(a+\alpha (a))^{-1}=(X_k+\alpha (a)Y_k)\alpha (a) \\ = & \alpha (a)X_k+\alpha (a)^2Y_k=\alpha (a)X_k+(a\alpha (a)+1)Y_k \\ = & Y_k+\alpha (a)[X_k+aY_k]  \\ \Rightarrow X_{k+1}=Y_k \ \ , \ \ &  Y_{k+1}= X_k+aY_k\end{align*} 
Άρα έχουμε ότι \begin{align*}  \text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(X_{k+1}) &=  \text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(Y_k)\overset{ Ε.Υ. }{ = }k-1 \\   \text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(Y_{k+1}) &=  \max \{\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(X_k), \text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(aY_k)\}=\max \{\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(X_k), \text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(a)+\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}(Y_k)\} \\ & \overset{ Ε.Υ. }{ = }  \max \{k-2, 1+k-1\}=\max \{k-2, k\}=k\end{align*} 


\end{description} 


\end{enumerate} 
\end{proof}
```

and the output is the following:

[image]

Is there a command so that after Απόδειξη(Proof) the first sentence i. is at the next line?

Also I have used the command '\overset{ Ε.Υ. }{ = }' where "Ε.Υ." should be in greek but at the output it appears in english "E.U.". Why?

---

I have used the following packages:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,greek]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdots} 

\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}  

\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Λήμμα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Θεώρημα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{mydef}{Ορισμός}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{example}{Παράδειγμα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[chapter] 
\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[chapter]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
  [\vspace{2ex}\titlerule] 

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{} 

\DeclareMathOperator{\Char}{char} 

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete minimal example (with preamble)?

Comment: What do you mean? What should I post? @Bernard

Comment: The  preamble of your document. We need to know which packages you used to obtain this resultn and try to propose solutions.

Comment: I added the packages I used in my initial post above... @Bernard

Comment: Ευχαριστώ, @Mary Star

Comment: I found my error at "\overset{ Ε.Υ. }{ = }". It should be "\overset{\text{ Ε.Υ. }}{ = }". @Bernard

Comment: Yes I saw that. And most probably you should use `\stackrel{ Ε.Υ. }{ = }`. For the problem of a new line after `Απόδειξη`, it should be easy to do with the `ntheorem` package. I'll see if I can do it with `amsthm`.

Answer (score 3):

It was enough to add a `\leavevmode` command just after `\begin{proof}`. If you want `Απόδειξη` to be systematically printed on a line of its own, I know only how to do it with `ntheorem`. Btw, with the latter package, the end-of-proof symbol would be much better (ans automatically) placed when a proof ends up in a equation.

I took the liberty to replace loading of `enumerate` with `enumitem`, with option `shortlabels`, as it provides the same functionality, and is much more powerful for customisation of lists.

Please note there exists a `\deg` math operator, so you didn't have to write `\text{\foreignlanguage{english}{deg}}`. Also, I replaced `\overset` with `stackrel`, which I found more appropriate.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathdots}

\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newtheorem{mylemma}{Λήμμα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Θεώρημα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{mydef}{Ορισμός}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Παράδειγμα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Πόρισμα}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Παρατήρηση}[chapter]

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}}
  [\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Char}{char}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\leavevmode
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item \begin{description}
\item[Βάση επαγωγής] : Για $m=2$ έχουμε $X_2(a)+\alpha (a)Y_2(a)=(\alpha (a))^2=a\alpha (a)+1$. Άρα $X_2(a)=1, Y_2(a)=a$. Δηλαδή $\deg (X_2)=0=2-2$ και $\deg(Y_2)=1=2-1$.
\item[Επαγωγική υπόθεση] : Υποθέτουμε ότι ισχύει για $m=k$, δηλαδή $\deg(X_k)=k-2$ και $\deg(Y_k)=k-1$. (Ε.Υ.)
\item[Επαγωγικό βήμα] : Θα δείξουμε ότι ισχύει για $m=k+1$, δηλαδή $\deg(X_{k+1})=k-1$ και $\deg Y_{k+1})=k$.
\begin{align*}X_{k+1}+\alpha Y_{k+1}= & (a+\alpha (a))^{-(k+1)}=(a+\alpha (a))^{-k}(a+\alpha (a))^{-1} \\ = & (X_k+\alpha (a)Y_k)(a+\alpha (a))^{-1}=(X_k+\alpha (a)Y_k)\alpha (a) \\ = & \alpha (a)X_k+\alpha (a)^2Y_k=\alpha (a)X_k+(a\alpha (a)+1)Y_k \\ = & Y_k+\alpha (a)[X_k+aY_k] \\ \Rightarrow X_{k+1}=Y_k \ \ , \ \ & Y_{k+1}= X_k+aY_k\end{align*}
Άρα έχουμε ότι \begin{align*} \deg(X_{k+1}) &= \deg(Y_k)\stackrel{\text{Ε.Υ.}}{=}k-1 \\ \deg(Y_{k+1}) &= \max \{\deg(X_k), \deg(aY_k)\}=\max \{\deg(X_k), \deg(a)+\deg(Y_k)\} \\ & \stackrel{\text{Ε.Υ }}{=} \max \{k-2, 1+k-1\}=\max \{k-2, k\}=k\deg Y\end{align*}

\end{description}
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-) I have also an other question... When we put the letter "a" between $ and $, it seems more like the greek letter \alpha, or not? Is there a command so that it appears as "a" ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: At the picture you posted above at the first line at the equation $X_2(a)+\alpha (a)Y_2(a)=...$ isn't the "a" similar to \alpha ?

Comment: Superficially, yes, but that's the standard fonts for TeX. It's another problem to find fonts for Greek that match a math font… There is fourier and erewhon, which Greek characters, but I suppose you should compile with `XeLaTeX`: as far as I know, there's no support for Greek in pdfLaTeX.